# pegar o quanto um vídeo já foi carregado (buffer)

Tags: javascript

Como posso pegar o valor do quanto um vídeo já foi carregado (buffer)? 
Exemplo:
Supondo que tenho um vídeo de 5 minutos, então de acordo que vou assistindo ele vai sendo carregado, mas como pegar esse valor de carregamento?. Posso estar vendo o vídeo na parte 02:30, mas o vídeo já pode ter sido carregado até os 03:00, então nesse caso ele foi carregado 30 segundos a mais. Procurei algum recurso do JavaScript que faça isso, mas não consegui encontrar nada sobre buffer (acredito que o nome seja esse mesmo).

Answer (score 2):

Olá Otavio tudo certo?

Dei uma pesquisada sobre isso e achei um conteúdo no site https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/buffering_seeking_time_ranges

O conteúdo está em inglês mas basicamente temos a propriedade buffered que retorna um objeto do tipo TimeRanges que também contém outros atributos.

> O TimeRanges nos informará quais partes da mídia foram baixadas. Isso
>   geralmente é contíguo, mas se o usuário pular enquanto a mídia estiver
>   armazenando em buffer, ele poderá conter furos.

Para mais informações acesse a fonte de onde extrai estas informações:

[Buffer de mídia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/buffering_seeking_time_ranges)

Abraços!